# How to install and use mbpipe

Tags: mapbox, mbtiles

`mbpipe` is a simple utility to batch process images in an MBTiles database (sqlite) by piping them to an image processing program.

But how does one install and use it?

[It says here](https://github.com/mapbox/node-mbtiles/wiki/Post-processing-MBTiles-with-MBPipe) that mbpipe comes with the mbtiles node.js module, that is installed with the command `npm install -g mbtiles`.

However after doing that there is in fact something in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mbtiles` but the "mbpipe" command or script cannot be found anywhere on my machine.

What should one do...?

Edit: on the [github page for node-mbtiles](https://github.com/mapbox/node-mbtiles/issues/31) it apparently says that the `mbpipe` utility was removed from the `mbtiles` module, but no one seems to be following up on this issue.

Is there another utility to do the same? (It should be pretty straightforward: extract images from an sqlite db, send them to a program for processing, re-insert the processed image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find MBPipe in the bin dir of [earlier releases](https://github.com/mapbox/node-mbtiles/releases/tag/v0.2.2) of the npm mbtiles package. Once you bring it down you'll need to run npm install to read the package.json file and install the deps in it.  Getting the sqlite3  library [to compile on windows](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/Building-On-Windows) was a bit tricky for me as I recall. I think I eventually found a precompiled 'binary' on the webs somewhere.

I mainly use it with [pngquant](http://pngquant.org/).  On windows, throw that binary in a directory and add it to your path var and you should be good to go with the mbpipe examples that you've linked to above.

Another thing to note, when I originally starting using it, I didn't understand the console output. When it starts it outputs a little graph and then appends hash # symbols underneath the graph to show progress.

I use it and it def. helps to optimize my caches.